# Repeating first value within the group in a table using awk

Tags: awk

I have a list like following:

```
group       Values
  0         aa_bb_25_0_1
  0         273 
  0         60
  1         aa_bb_7_0_2
  1         335
  2         aa_bb_65_1_1
  2         456
  3         aa_bb_98_0_1
```

I would like to take the only first entry that starts with "aa_bb" within respective group and modfiy the tabe like following

```
group  Values        Modified.values
      0  aa_bb_25_0_1  aa_bb_25_0_1
      0  273           aa_bb_25_0_1  
      0  60            aa_bb_25_0_1   
      1  aa_bb_7_0_2   aa_bb_7_0_2   
      1  335           aa_bb_7_0_2
      2  aa_bb_65_1_1  aa_bb_65_1_1
      2  456           aa_bb_65_1_1
      3  aa_bb_98_0_1  aa_bb_98_0_1
```

I tried the following code but it gave me the output exactly like the input

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '$3!="" {three=$2} $0!="" {$3=three; print $0}' test.tx
```

Comment: wrt the code you wrote - every line is 2 fields so you don't have any lines where `$3!=""` so what made you think it'd do anything?

Answer (score 2):

Give this one-liner a try (it ignored the header line):

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t"  'NR==1{next}$2~/^aa_bb/{p=$2}{print $0,p}' file
```

Comment: You may wanna pipe to `column -t` for pretty alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Awk and `column` for output control:

```
awk '{
    print $0,($1!=p?(NR==1?"Modified.":"")$2:q)
    if($1!=p) {
        p=$1                                      # p is the previous group
        q=$2
    }
}' file | column -t
group  Values        Modified.Values
0      aa_bb_25_0_1  aa_bb_25_0_1
0      273           aa_bb_25_0_1
0      60            aa_bb_25_0_1
1      aa_bb_7_0_2   aa_bb_7_0_2
1      335           aa_bb_7_0_2
2      aa_bb_65_1_1  aa_bb_65_1_1
2      456           aa_bb_65_1_1
3      aa_bb_98_0_1  aa_bb_98_0_1
```